# error al conectar base de datos php+sql

Tags: php, mysql

buenas me surgio un problema y nose a que se deba,
estaba intentando conectar a la base de datos mysql desde php,
el codigo es el siguiente

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','depru','3308');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "<h4>error al establecer conexion con bd</h4> ".mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo "<h4>conexion exitosa puede proceder con el estudio</h4>";
}
```

el codigo esta bien, ya lo probe con mi pc de escritorio y funcionaba correctamente,
el problema es que ahora estoy intentadolo desde una notebook (no tengo la pc)
y me da el siguiente error
**no se puede establecer conexion ya que el equipo de destino denego expresamente dicha conexion** alguien sabe a que se debe y como solucionarlo?, gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste que el host, usuario, contraseña, nombre de base de datos y puerto estén correctos? Además, el usuario que provees tiene que tener permisos para poder conectarse a la base de datos.

Comment: si todos los parametros estan correctamente ingresados, y es el usuario root tiene todos los permisos, no creo que sea ese el problema, ya que me dice que el equipo denego la conexion

Comment: bueno solucione el problema, no le estableci ningun port si esto lo hacia desde un pc de escritorio me daba error ya que por defecto viene el port de mariadb, pero aca no le estableci ninguno y funciono correctamente el codigo, quizas alguien sepa explicar mejor a que se debe.